# JSF + Primefaces - How to stop RemoteCommand from running on page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use RemoteCommand to call a backing Bean's method using Javascript, but all it does is call it on page load.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
       <h:body>

          <h:form prependId="false">
              <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{myBean.printHello()}" name="jsMethod" autoRun="false" />
          </h:form>

       </h:body>   

    </html>
```

Note that I didn't even put any Javascript code in there, and still it calls the method printHello(). And if I do put the Javascript there, it is completly ignored.

How do I fix this? I've seen people stop using the remoteCommand and doing some workarounds with hidding remoteButton, but that's not what I need.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post your mnaged bean code

Comment: On the first look your code looks fine. `autoRun=false` isn't even necessary because this should be default setting. Is `prependId=false` necessary or set knowingly? If not, have you tried without this option?

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour. What do you  see when you do a view-source in the browser?